# TypeScript типизация

Tags: typescript

Стал ковырять typescript. И непонятно как типизировать подобное.

```
var firstArray = ["a", "b", "c"]; // инициализируем переменную, содержащую массив строк
var secondArray = [1, 2, 3]; // инициализируем переменную, содержащую массив чисел

var newArray= firstArray.concat( secondArray ); // объединяем массивы

console.log( newArray ); // результат ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3]
```

Понятно, что на практике лучше, чтобы подобные разношерстные массивы не возникали. Но как их все таки типизировать? Пробовал и так `[number, string]`, и так `Array<number | string>` что то все равно ошибку пишет.

Comment: `const newArray= ([] as (number | string)[]).concat(firstArray, secondArray);` или просто `const newArray= [...firstArray, ...secondArray];`

Comment: Спасибо друг. первый вариант сработал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=61&pln=6&pc=52#code/G4QwTgBAZglmDOAXAgmMICeEC8EDaARCAQDQQEBGp5AxgQLoDcAUKJPAKY0D2AdgCap0WXHgCMZAExkAzE2atwEXhwDuQzDggAKWAhRpNIeDqRgYvAOYQAPsoCuAWwocwASjz03AOh68aIIjanH6ChhhuLMx+8NwANhzecdyW2irq4ZEQAPTZEIACIICsIIDsIIDCIIDcIIAyIIBCIIAMINX4RNSUzXRkEhDSEHJAA)

```
var firstArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
var secondArray = [1, 2, 3];

var newArray = (firstArray as (string | number)[]).concat(secondArray);

console.log(newArray); // результат ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Спасибо! именно то что я хотел увидеть.Без изменения кода с использованием  spred

Answer (score 0):

1. Замечание к вопросу. Всегда прикладываете ошибку, если она есть.
2. Типизировать можно кучей способов, но на мой взгляд, лучше максимально позволять TS выводить типы самому. И наилучшее решение для вашего вопроса, опять же на мой взгляд, это использовать современный синтаксис(`spread syntax`):

```typescript
const firstArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
const secondArray = [1, 2, 3];

const newArray = [...firstArray,...secondArray];
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=25&pln=6&pc=13#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwE7QIJKQQwJ4wLwwDaARJsQDQzEBGFVwxAugNwCwAUKJLBAKZcATdFlwFCARkoAmSgGYWHDl2gwwvAO7Cc%20IgDp9iFFC3Zy%203X0EmF7JeAggANr12OQAcwAUqjSZgBKZiA)